# Microsoft Word asking to use a document for "style"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I received a message box from Microsoft Word quoting a large piece of a password protected document and asking if it could be used for "style". 
There was a comment that the document would be anonymous, and also a box "No, and don't ask me again" which I checked. 
How does it access a document saved on my computer, but not on-line?

Comment: Which version of Word? Which version of Windows? Do you have any additional information for us?

Comment: Word 2010; Windows 7;

Comment: Not much more information;I clicked "No" before thinking to save the message.